# access overloaded operator in c++

Tags: c++

I have overloaded the [] operator in my class. here is the implementation

```
Node* List::operator [](int index) const{
    Node* p = head_;

    for (int i = 0; i < index; i++){
            p = p->link();
    }

    return p;
}
```

I have another function in the class in which I want to access the Node* returned. one of the lines is

```
if ((n = index_of_name(artistName)) >= 0){
  Node* p = // code needed here
}
```

I want to be able to access the node at n by using the overloaded[]. How can I do that?

Comment: Sniff sniff sniff.... smells kinda homeworky.
Everything from the clean code up to that point to the "code needed here" part....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
(*this)[n]
```

Comment: @lothar - Thanks! I couldn't remember how to use the arrow op to do it, since I always use the above.